# Can be Vue.observable be used as Vuex replacement?

Tags: vue.js

New Vue 2.6 introduce `Vue.observable`. I read docs, but still can't understand if `Vue.observable` can be used as Vuex?

Could anybody explain me this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a shorthand for old: `new Vue({data() { return {...}; } })`.

If you need data which is shared between components you had to create `new Vue(...)`. Now you can use observable - `Vue.observable({...})` and use it in render-functions or computeds.

So, I think it is not Vuex replacement, because Vuex cares about global App data and has nice debug tools.